# Excel: populate a new column by bringing in the corresponding cell from another tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

Need help to write the formula that can populate a new column called ‘region2’ In the “Diarrhea Data” tab, by bringing in the corresponding 'region' for each 'district' from the “District Data” tab.

[“Diarrhea Data” tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anIZc.png)

[“District Data” tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gawQ8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the 'Diarrhea Data' worksheet's G2 then fill down,

```
=index('District Data'!b:b, match(d2, 'District Data'!c:c, 0))
```

It's unclear from your sample 'data' how this differs from the region already in 'Diarrhea Data'!c:c.

Comment: I tried and the first one works. But the others are displaying error message, and I can't tell why. Here is a google drive link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l9bpsx5lSPIkD1HyRX96t1nb0GOE_D5G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You changed the ranges from full column to a set range without using $ to lock the rows. The range changed as you copied it down. Stick with full columns or lock the rows like `'District Data'!b$2:b$217` and `'District Data'!c$2:c$217` (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kZuXZYYEdVR7kNeXJhYyroQ_N40SNI8P31RmsIQ4Lxw/edit?usp=sharing)